# Login with $cordovaOauth issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ngcordova

```
function facebookLogin() {
            $cordovaOauth.facebook("948645908488914", ["email"]).then(function (result) {
            displayData($http, result.access_token);
        }, function (error) {
            alert("Error: " + error);
        });
    }
```

I'm not certain what the email value should be. Should it be the user's email address from witch the token should be obtained from ?

I am receiving the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
    at Object.facebook (local://simulator/js/ng-cordova.min.js:24:6458)
    at facebookLogin (local://simulator/js/app/controllers/ng-controllers-all.js:47:23)
    at m.$scope.login (local://simulator/js/app/controllers/ng-controllers-all.js:43:9)
    at fn (eval at <anonymous> (local://simulator/js/angular.min.js:210:400), <anonymous>:2:206)
    at local://simulator/js/ionic-angular.min.js:20:5713
    at m.$eval (local://simulator/js/angular.min.js:134:83)
    at m.$apply (local://simulator/js/angular.min.js:134:309)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (local://simulator/js/ionic-angular.min.js:20:5695)
    at HTMLButtonElement.n.event.dispatch (local://simulator/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3:6466)
    at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (local://simulator/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3:3241)(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:107
```

Comment: It's a request for `email` info. So "email" is a keyword https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-facebook-example

Comment: How are you trying to run your application?  I'm not familiar with local://simulator.  That isn't a browser based simulator is it?

Comment: I am using Teleriks - Device simulator , I am busy with a mobile application and want to login via facebook or goolge plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`email` is the permission that you are asking for, You pass the permissions like:

```
$cordovaOauth.facebook("APP_ID", ['public_profile','user_friends','email','user_groups','user_likes']).then(function(result) {
// Code
```

the problem I guess is that you are not testing on a device.

Comment: Hi , now im facing a different problem. I have decided to deploy the application on my phone , but now I am receiving the following exception when deploying the Application on my phone.Warning: Failed to install 'com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect':Error: Variable(s) missing: APP_ID, APP_NAME

Comment: if you are using $cordovaOauth you don't need the Facebook connect plugin, run 
`cordova plugin rm com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect`
and try again, if this works please accept the answer
You have to run that in a terminal at the root of your application